# php page being downloaded instead of being processed while accessing outside a particular domain

Tags: php, apache2

I have installed PHP5 with apache 2.2.16 and trying to serve an application based on php.

I am able to acess this application inside a particular domain (php scripts are processed normally) but when i trying to access it outside that domain my php pages are being downloaded instead of being processed ?

What could be the reason?

Comment: Check your apache virtual host setting on the domain that does not work. It seems to missing some handler for PHP. **OR** compare the virtual host setting that is working to the non-working

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Apache and PHP5 are properly installed?  If Apache is not actually parsing the php files after you've installed PHP5 and restarted the server, install `libapache2-mod-php5`. This is usually installed when you initially install the PHP5 package, but perhaps it might have been moved or removed intentionally or inadvertently by other packages which need other PHP versions.

You may also need to actually enable PHP by doing `sudo a2enmod php5` followed by `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. If `sudo a2enmod php5` returns "`$ This module does not exist!`", you should purge (not just remove) the `libapache2-mod-php5` package and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks Chris for ur response but am on windows side ...and in a particular domain its working fine but in other domain sometime php file being downloaded and sometime it show php script code ..am sure  Apache and PHP5 are properly installed

Comment: nd one more thing in second case where browser is showing php script code after refreshing the code php is being executed

Comment: Very odd-- perhaps this is a permissions issue? Verify that the file permissions on a working file match up with those of your non-working file.